# How to split a big number using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

This is my number "1508261".
In the end I want to have a List of ("15","08","261").
Meaning, the pattern should always create two new numbers with two digits in each and the remaining digits should be all included in the last (third) number.

I tried using this approach but it returns ("1508261"):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1,})");    
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1508261");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
       list.add(matcher.group());
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using regex? Why not a simple substring operation?

Comment: @RyanS maybe the input could have extra leading characters that are not numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your snippet tests the whole pattern against the input string, not each group separately. You might want to use `Matcher.matches()` and `Matcher.group(int)` instead of `Matcher.find()`:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1,})");    
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1508261");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        for(int i = 1;i <= matcher.groupCount();i++)
            list.add(matcher.group(i));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
```

Live example in Ideone [here](http://ideone.com/5E5cd1).

Also note that `Matcher.group()` and `Matcher.group(0)` do the same job. More info can be found in the [Oracle Java Regex Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).